# How to Hide and Show the ComponentArt Slider inside the div in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

The componentart slider is given in div ,when we click the button outside of the div , the div will show and hide the componentart slider(this is the concept)..i tried many javascripts and jquery but i got some errors in sliders...

In this URL(http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/scheduler/features/core_features/WebForm1.aspx)->this is i want

but i got some errors in slider..

(my error is when we click show/hide button the slider will collapsed)

<------this is my tried code---------->

```
function toggle(id) {
        var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
            if (state == '') {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
            }
        }
    function onloadDivScheduler()
    {

     document.getElementById('divScheduler').style.display = 'none'; 
    }    
</script>
```

<---------------------->
<------HTMl---------->

```
 <div id="main">
 <a href="#" onclick="toggle('divScheduler');">Settings</a>
  </div>
 <div id="hidden"> "My content (componentart slider)"
</div>
```

<---------------------->

give me the solutions...

Thanks in advance....

<---------------------------------->
Now i got partial output form this code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(id) {
            var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
                if (state == 'block') {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
    </script>


 <div id="main"> <a href="#" onclick="toggle('hidden');">Settings</a>
 </div>
 <div id="hidden"> ("content")</div>
```

then now i want hide my div when page appears but in this code the div is shown the div content when page starts ...

will u give the sample for hide the div when page starts and when we click the button it show the div...

Comment: -1 show some code. Show what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleDiv(divName){
   $("#"+divName).toggle();
}

<a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv('hidden');">Settings</a>
```

why is this marked down..

Comment: it's not working..will you please give your complete javascript for your above code..

Comment: that is the complete javascript. you need jquery running.

Comment: forgot my hash tag, try it again. also update your jquery one of these days

Comment: This is the solution.. from the content YOU provided us with you are trying to hide and show the div ID'd 'divScheduler'... use jquery's toggle functionality on this. if you are not giving us the right information (as i see no divScheduler other than that you are referencing it in javascript), please update your question.